# How to execute an action from another controller without leaving the current controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # call the action do_something from ImagesController
    # continue in the normal flow
  end
end

class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def do_something
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to call the action `do_something` in the `ImagesController` from `UsersController` but after it is executed I want to continue in the normal flow of the `create` action, few questions:

- Is it a bad practice?
- How can I do that? Do I have to create an instance of the `ImagesController` and then call the action or is there another way?

Comment: Yes, it's a bad practice. You should find another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could technically create an instance of the other controller and call methods on that, but it is tedious, error prone and highly not recommended.

If that function is common to both controllers, you should probably have it in ApplicationController or another superclass controller of your creation.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def common_to_all_controllers
    # some code
  end
end

class SuperController < ApplicationController
  def common_to_some_controllers
    # some other code
  end
end

class MyController < SuperController
  # has access to common_to_all_controllers and common_to_some_controllers
end

class MyOtherController < ApplicationController
  # has access to common_to_all_controllers only
end
```

another method is

```
# lib/common_stuff.rb
module CommonStuff
  def common_thing
    # code
  end
end



# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
require 'common_stuff'
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include CommonStuff
  # has access to common_thing
end
```

source - [Calling a method from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225518/calling-a-method-from-another-controller)

Answer (score 0):

this is possible actually. And not that hard.

That said. It is bad practice. Very bad practice.

What you want to do is extract the logic you do in the controller you want to invoke into a service object or move it into a model. Alternativly you could also make your first controller inherit from the one you are trying to invoke.

So, how to call a controller?

`TheController.new.dispatch(:index, request)`

Comment: what do I have to put in the request parameter? an objet to pass to the action if needed?

Comment: The request should be of the same type af the request object you would normally get in a controller: ActionController::Request.