# Rails 4 calling model from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to get data data from another model. I found an answer from 
[Calling a method from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225518/calling-a-method-from-another-controller)

but the question was so vaque thereofre the answer is vague. Before you give me a "Down" for this, please expalin why???

THE ERROR: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

Home (action)

```
 @featured_courses = get_featured_courses

 private

 def get_featured_courses
      Course.all
 end
```

view StaticPages#Home

```
 <% @featured_courses.each do |course| %>
     <%= course.name %>

 <% end %>
```

This code work when I try it on the course controller and index view but not in the static_pages controller. Therefore, I think it is because I am using a different controller. can anyone help. I need this project to be up in three days.

Comment: Seems like you must have a typo somewhere (perhaps not shown here).  You can access any model from any controller.  ie I have Model `Course` and a controller "Blueberries", I can still have an action in that controller that does `Course.all`.  Can you show us the actual code from the other controller

Comment: I got it. I was rendering another layout. And I place the information on the bottom of "render layout: home" instead of before the render.