# Rails redirect_to update_path/update_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 5, how do you run update on a model, and then execute an update of another controller?
I know it's done with redirect_to, but not sure how exactly. Here is what I have so far:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
  def update
    ...
    redirect_to author_update_path(id: book.author.id.to_s)
  end
end

class AuthorController < ApplicationController
  def update
    ...
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end
end
```

I am on a book page and I updated some fields that belong to the book (like the book title). But then I want to run the update of the author.

I am getting NoMethodError so far...

What do I do?

EDIT

Let me explain it clearly:

My UPDATE action in the authors controller is hundreds of lines long. I need to run it for the nested author. My issue is not in updating the author from within the Books controller update action. My problem is that I need to run the author controller UPDATE action via the UPDATE action of the books controller.
Copy pasting the UPDATE action of the Author controller into the Update action of the Books controller is not an option.

Comment: NoMethodError what? Where? Please provide more context (code). Regarding running a method from one controller to another, it's not generally advised or a best practice at all, but if you must, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225518/calling-a-method-from-another-controller

Comment: It's redirecting to the show action. I am unable to redirect to update. I believe already included all the code that is relevant to the question

Comment: What's the method that's undefined?

Comment: I think I agree with you. I'll just create a helper method and avoid the monkey patching...

Comment: The public methods of your controllers should only correspond to an HTTP request and nothing more. The protected and private methods should set up the context surrounding that request. If you find yourself trying to do something outside of that scope, you're probably doing something you're not supposed to be doing :)

Comment: Don't do that. Redirect is sending a response of the request and invoke new request from the client's side. So, that need more client's resources and server's too. Put all logic to the same action when them related to the same path and only then write a single redirect if redirect needed(in your case any redirect has no sense).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do this different, like:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
  def update
    ...

    #update the author
    author = Author.find(book.author.id)
    #if you need, you can use Author.update(fields_to_update_with_values)
    author.touch

    #later redirect
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end
end
```

And you can set in your model associations, an auto "update".  [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#touch) say:

> If you set the :touch option to true, then the updated_at or
>   updated_on timestamp on the associated object will be set to the
>   current time whenever this object is saved or destroyed

**Update** I recommend that you use a service object and migrate you author controller update code to the service. This is a good practice for easify your controller and helpfull for your issue.

You can follow the [Service Objects in Ruby on Rails…and you](https://hackernoon.com/service-objects-in-ruby-on-rails-and-you-79ca8a1c946e) guide by Rob Race.

Comment: My UPDATE action in the authors controller is hundreds of lines long. I need to run it for the nested author. My issue is not in updating the author. My problem is that I need to run the author controller UPDATE action via the UPDATE action of the books controller.

Answer (score 0):

For complex actions that need to be shared, I believe the only solution is to extract the actions into a new module. Here is a complete detailed answer for those looking for a similar answer:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
  def update
    # Find the book and then the author of the book
    book = Book.find(params[:id])
    author = book.author
    # create an instance of the author updater and run the update action
    author_updater = Modules::AuthorUpdater.new(author)
    author_updater.update_author

    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end
end

class AuthorController < ApplicationController
  def update
    author = Author.find(params[:id])
    # create an instance of the author updater and run the update action
    author_updater = Modules::AuthorUpdater.new(author)
    author_updater.update_author

    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end
end

# Place this as author_updater.rb inside lib/modules/
class Modules::AuthorUpdater
    def initialize(author)
        @author = author
    end
    def update_author
        # update actions go here...
    end
end
```